# PHP with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Why is this function working only when I refresh my page and not when I click on the button?

```
function postLoveIt()
{
    <?php $num =  getloveDiamond($this->item->id)+1;?>
    <?php updateloveDiamond($this->item->id, $num); ?>
    document.getElementById('loveit').value=<?php echo getloveDiamond($this->item->id); ?>;
}
```

this is the button code:

```
<form >
    <input type="button"  value="<?php echo getloveDiamond($this->item->id); ?>" id="loveit"
    onclick="postLoveIt();"/>  
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure how its even working first time...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [~20k similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+variable+javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the relationship between PHP and its output. In the code above, you are causing PHP to generate an HTML file including some JavaScript code. The PHP code runs when the page is generated. The HTML is then loaded into a browser with the JavaScript.

If you want this JavaScript to do something on the server, you need to either send an XMLrpc request or have it open an iframe to get PHP on the server to do something.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the value from the PHP, then it executes before the page is loaded. You need to use **AJAX** to fetch dynamic data. So, after clicking the button, fire an AJAX call.

But this will not even work if you use this normally!